# average of all rows corresponing to all unique rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with two columns:

```
A = [[1,1,1,2,3,1,2,3],[0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1]]
```

for all uniques in first column, I want average of the values corresponding to it. For example

```
B = [[1,2,3], [0.175, 0.15, 0.2]]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the `0.233` be `0.175` as `(0.1+0.2+0.2+0.2)/4 == 0.175`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following is the standard numpy approach for these kind of computations. The call to `np.unique` can be skipped if the entries of `A[0]` are small integers, but it makes the whole operation more robust and independent of the actual data.

```
>>> A = [[1,1,1,2,3,1,2,3],[0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1]]
>>> unq, unq_idx = np.unique(A[0], return_inverse=True)
>>> unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=A[1])
>>> unq_counts = np.bincount(unq_idx)
>>> unq_avg = unq_sum / unq_counts
>>> unq
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> unq_avg
array([ 0.175,  0.15 ,  0.2  ])
```

You could of course  then stack both arrays, although that will convert `unq` to float dtype:

```
>>> np.vstack((unq, unq_avg))
array([[ 1.   ,  2.   ,  3.   ],
       [ 0.175,  0.15 ,  0.2  ]])
```

Comment: This will work only when the weights in numpy bincount are integers? If I supply non-integer weights, it throws me an error: TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type

Comment: `np.bincount` requires that the weights be castable to `np.double` type. It doesn't work e.g. with complex numbers. But integers and floats should all be fair game.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is:

```
In [37]: a=np.array([[1,1,1,2,3,1,2,3],[0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1]])
In [38]: np.array([list(set(a[0])), [np.average(np.compress(a[0]==i, a[1])) for i in set(a[0])]])
Out[38]:
array([[ 1.   ,  2.   ,  3.  ],
       [ 0.175,  0.15 ,  0.2 ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this more efficiently by using `np.histogram` to first get the sums of the values in `A[1]` corresponding to each unique index in `A[1]`, then the total number of occurrences for each unique index.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,1,1,2,3,1,2,3],[0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1]])

# NB for n unique values in A[0] we want (n + 1) bin edges, such that
# A[0].max() < bin_edges[-1]
bin_edges = np.arange(A[0].min(), A[0].max()+2, dtype=np.int)

# the `weights` parameter means that the count for each bin is weighted
# by the corresponding value in A[1]
weighted_sums,_ = np.histogram(A[0], bins=bin_edges, weights=A[1])

# by calling `np.histogram` again without the `weights` parameter, we get
# the total number of occurrences of each unique index
index_counts,_ = np.histogram(A[0], bins=bin_edges)

# now just divide the weighted sums by the total occurrences
urow_avg = weighted_sums / index_counts

print urow_avg
# [ 0.175  0.15   0.2  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

yet another efficient numpy only solution, using [reduceat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
A=np.array(zip(*[[1,1,1,2,3,1,2,3],[0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1]]),
        dtype=[('id','int64'),('value','float64')])
A.sort(order='id')
unique_ids,idxs = np.unique(A['id'],return_index=True)
avgs = np.add.reduceat(A['value'],idxs)
#divide by the number of samples to obtain the actual averages.
avgs[:-1]/=np.diff(idxs)
avgs[-1]/=A.size-idxs[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this as follows:

```
values = {}

# get all values for each index
for index, value in zip(*A):
    if index not in values:
        values[index] = []
    values[index].append(value)

# create average for each index
for index in values:
    values[index] = sum(values[index]) / float(len(values[index]))

B = np.array(zip(*values.items()))
```

For your example, this gives me:

```
>>> B
array([[ 1.   ,  2.   ,  3.   ],
       [ 0.175,  0.15 ,  0.2  ]])
```

You could simplify slightly using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = defaultdict(list)

for index, value in zip(*A):
    values[index].append(value)
```