# Max stress node

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to generate scripts to automatically create views of a model at the max stress location. 
I know I could read every node and check the stress of each with python but this will take a while due to the size of the model. As this feature appears in CAE is there an easy way to script this? 
Once I know the node I am interested in I can then utilize the location of this to generate the views I want.

Comment: I've never used it, but I think whet you want is in the 6.14 Scripting Reference section 34.31.2 `maxEnvelope(...)`.  As usual Abaqus scripting reference is not very helpful at figuring out how to use it though.

Comment: @DanielForsman I don't think maxEnvelope does what you think. I think it creates a new field which is the max among a list of input fields.  The manual is not clear at all...  It is annoying we can have the legend display the max value instantly but it seems you need a python loop to actually grab that value.

Comment: btw if you want to play with it, the usage of `maxEnvelope` is like `maxEnvelope([frame.fieldOutputs['S'].getScalarField(componentLabel='S11'),])`  . (This seems to just return the input since there is only one field in the list )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW here is the best approach I know..:

```
 field=frame.fieldOutputs['S'].getScalarField(componentLabel='S11')
 maxp = max([ (g.data,g.elementLabel,g.integrationPoint) for g in field.values ])
```

> ( 242.4324 , 10333 , 1 )

Considering what you are doing I think the max integration point value is likely what you want.  Getting the nodal average value will be a lot slower and more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

**Calculation of unique nodal stresses**

At first you have to think about what stress values you wan't to have. (max unique nodal stress of the whole tensor, Mises, MaxPrincipal,...)
If you wan't for example unique nodal Mises stresses you can calculate Mises stresses for each extrapolated stress tensor and than calculate the unique nodal stresses or the other way around. You will also find that option in the Abaqus CAE Gui.

In this answer I will show how to calculate the max stress value for a whole unique nodal stress tensor.

At first get the stress values.
If you have Abaqus Python 6.13 or newer installed use the FieldBulkData method to get your data. It is much faster as the value method shown in the answer of agentp. For example:

```
Field=odb.steps[Steps[0]].frames[1].fieldOutputs['S']
Field = Field.getSubset(position = ELEMENT_NODAL)
Values=Field.bulkDataBlocks[0].data
NodeLabels=Field.bulkDataBlocks[0].nodeLabels
```

Now we have the extrapolated stress values. The calculation of unique values is copied from:
[average of all rows corresponing to all unique rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298050/average-of-all-rows-corresponing-to-all-unique-rows)

```
NodeLabels_unique, unq_idx = np.unique(NodeLabels, return_inverse=True)
Values_Averaged=np.zeros((NodeLabels_unique.size,Values.shape[1]))
unq_counts = np.bincount(unq_idx)
for i in xrange(0,Values.shape[1]):
    unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=Values[:,i])
    Values_Averaged[:,i] = unq_sum / unq_counts

 #Index of max stress value
 max_ind=np.unravel_index(np.argmax(Values_Averaged),Values_Averaged.shape)

 #Print the results
 print("The max stress is at NodeLabel "+str(NodeLabels_unique[max_ind[0]])+ " its value is "+ str(Values_Averaged[max_ind]) +" MPa.")
```

On my Notebook the whole averaging process takes about 9s for 17,000,000 Element_Nodal values.

Comment: just trying to understand this by reading.. Where does `Values` come from? ( And I note you never use `S` )

Comment: I have edited the answer. The Values are the element nodal tensors. I think the most important part is to understand what the bincount method does. Before I found this Method I wrote a C function to do the averaging, but the shown Method isn't much slower than doing the averaging in C.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of [max9111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045774/max9111?tab=profile) is a really good approach but when running it it has a problem at the following line, at least when running it on Abaqus 6.16:

```
for i in xrange(0,Values.shape[1]):
    unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=Values[:,i])
    ...
```

The following error message appears:

```
ValueError: The weights and list don't have the same length.
```

I spent a huge amount of time to fix it. The working solution is as follow,

```
for i in xrange(0,Values.shape[1]):
    ValuesTemp = [item[i] for item in Values]
    unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=ValuesTemp)
    Values_Averaged[:,i] = unq_sum / unq_counts
```

The problem come from the way Abaqus stores data with the bulkDataBlocks which is not a standard list but an array of lists.